# HTML5 - image with clickable areas

Tags: css, html

I need the following to work in web and mobile web:

This is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        html, body{
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            border: 0;
            left: 0;
            top: 0;
        }

        #wrapper{
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
        }

        #person{
            position: relative;
            width: 559px;
            height: 687px;
            background: url(pics/person.png) no-repeat center center fixed;
            -webkit-background-size: cover;
            -moz-background-size: cover;
            -o-background-size: cover;
            background-size: cover;
        }
        .dot{
            position: absolute;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="person">
            <img src="pics/red-dot.png" class="dot" style="top: 110px; left: 314px">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to display the following image:
[image]

where I what to cover all white dot with red dots.
each dot is clickable and should toggle it's color on click (I'll use jQuery).

**My question:**
What is the best practice for cover all white dots (the main image) with red dots to look the same for all major browsers and in mobile-web pages ?

Note: Right now the background image stretch when I change the zoom and the red dot is moving.

Comment: Which are the minimum browsers versions you want to reach out?

Comment: Explorer 8 is the oldest.

Comment: I also know that I can use position fixed in mobile vesions

Comment: What do you mean "background image stretch when I change the zoom"? Your image has a fixed size, so how can it stretch? Are you talking about zooming on mobile browsers?

Comment: I already solved that problem, but the dots are moving with the scroll

Comment: Can you use an [area](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/area)?